# Reporting ICC for Linear Mixed Effect Models

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am planning to run some linear mixed effect models (a new method for me).
And I read one should report the ICC (interclass correlation coefficient).

I downloaded several packages but failed to compute it.

```
   ICC(DF, missing = T)
```

> **Error in data.frame(x.s, subs = rep(paste("S", 1:n.obs, sep = ""), nj)) :
> arguments imply differing number of rows: 898, 2245
> In addition: Warning message:
> In stack.data.frame(x) : non-vector columns will be ignored**

This is my data:

```
DF <- structure(list(ID = c("SR6", "YLG19", "YLG19", "SR5", "SR2", 
"TG5", "FB7", "SR9", "KBU15", "FB5"), sub_group = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("European Bullhead", 
"Salmonids"), class = "factor"), taxa = c("salmo.trutta", "oncorhynchus.mykiss", 
"oncorhynchus.mykiss", "salmo.trutta", "salmo.trutta", "salmo.trutta", 
"cottus.gobio", "cottus.gobio", "cottus.gobio", "cottus.gobio"
), sampling.site = c("oberer.seebach.ritrodat", "ybbs.lunz.grossau", 
"ybbs.lunz.grossau", "oberer.seebach.ritrodat", "oberer.seebach.ritrodat", 
"tagles.unten", "faltlbach", "oberer.seebach.ritrodat", "kothbergbach.unten", 
"faltlbach"), body_weight_g = c(4L, 8L, 8L, 20L, 26L, 42L, 6L, 
10L, 4L, 6L), PUFA = structure(c(3L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
1L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("SDA", "EPA", "ARA", "DHA"), class = "factor"), 
    organ = structure(c(2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 3L
    ), .Label = c("Brain", "Eyes", "Liver", "Muscles"), class = "factor"), 
    isotopic_value = c(-36.7301983, -39.5973755, -40.549113, 
    -35.6261828, -36.4038883, -46.085506, -39.0796303, NA, -41.6335499, 
    -41.484535)), row.names = c(289L, 488L, 487L, 280L, 242L, 
367L, 52L, 308L, 189L, 19L), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is my LMM:

```
isotopic_value ~ organ + body_weight_g  + (1 | ID)
```

What is it that I am doing wrong?
Cheers,
Nadine

Comment: The error is because your data frame contains columns with non-numeric values. The first argument to `ICC` is "a matrix or dataframe of ratings" _i.e._ numeric variables.

Comment: ah i tried that yesterday and it did not work but now it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
cols_ID <- sapply(1:ncol(DF),function(x) is.numeric(DF[,x]))

ICC(DF[,which(cols_ID)])
```